# Node-webkit Shell.showItemInFolder() on Windows XP

Tags: node-webkit

On two laptops:  Windows 7 and Windows XP.

```
<script>
var gui = require ('nw.gui');
gui.Shell.showItemInFolder ('C:\\nw\\myProject\\index.html');
</script>
```

Works (with escaped back-slashes, as shown) on Windows 7 system, fails silently on Windows XP.
I have seen issues posted with OSX and also with Windows 7, but not with XP. Incidently,
the other two Shell methods, openItem() and openExternal() both work perfectly on both 
laptops. 
Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thank you,
Jonathan

Comment: I've had similar behaviour, but the silent fail only happens when the file or location in question does not exist.